# Java double[][] to double[] without copy

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a lot of old code with big `double[][]` arrays and I need to flatten in a `double[]` array for a new library usage.
I don't want to copy, is there a simple way to re-reference the array like in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to do without a copy.

1. The memory with `double[][]` is not contiguous.
2. The "rows" in `double[][]` refer to `double[]` objects.
3. The memory occupied by `double[]` has to be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible without a copy<sup>1</sup>.

Unlike a Nd array in C, where math is performed to map onto a single contiguous object (and thus a cast might work; but ask a C language lawyer), *a "2d" array in Java **is** an Array (object) -of- Arrays (many objects).* This extends for each additional dimension.

That is, a 2d array in Java can be though of as a `double* []` in C, where each row/column of the secondary axis has been malloc'ed separately; and where accessing a cell requires two lookup operations, even if it still 'looks' like `double[][]` access.

---

<sup>1</sup> Because Java does not allow operator (ie. []) overloading even trying to wrap 1d-to-Nd access no longer looks like that of an array, but rather that of a List/ArrayList. In any case this would still require the individual lookups underneath.

Comment: @Alvins I didn't downvote. Also, votes are silent. If the voter wishes to explain why (and I think such should be encouraged) then they will.